# The Workplace is a toxic community

Tags: discussion

I've just joined *The Workplace* yesterday and it has been a very bad experience. I've asked [two](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/185376/135123) [questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/185433/135123), both pretty much the same. After there was no more hope for the first question, I asked the second one providing more context (that I think is not really necessary to answer the question, but it was demanded in the first one). Again, the downvotes came in almost immediatly.

It occured to me that there might have been a misunderstanding based on cultural differences. I addressed this in my last edit, but it was in vain. The question was already closed and downvoted to -6.

I've never experienced anything like this on stackoverflow, where I am a member for years. It is evident, that:

1. The Workplace is not welcoming to new contributers.
2. Many comments showed in their wording a clear tendency to justify my question being bad rather than asking for clarification.
3. The clarifications I tried to make were largely ignored or rather cherry picked for things to criticize.
4. Many contributers focused on *why* I was asking this question and addressing misconceptions they had about my questions. Few actually responded to the question itself.

This begs the question of *why* is The Workplace such a toxic community? Of course, I can't know this, but I have some thoughts:

1. The Workplace is probably a vastly smaller community than stackoverflow, making it easier for a few bad apples to ruin the experience for everybody.
2. Many people hate their jobs and I wouldn't be surprised if people rather often misuse this platform to ventilate their frustration. I don't think anybody would accuse me of that; but maybe this has let some users to have a rather loose finger over the downvote button.

I don't have any illusions that I could make some of the haters of my question reconsider; they would probably just come up with new justifications for my questions being bad. The rest of you however I ask this: Is this the kind of community you want to be a part of? If not, is there anything you can do about it?

Comment: I don't agree that The Workplace is a toxic community. It may well have a few folks that aren't as welcoming as they could be, along with a handful that are clearly "close happy". That said, you were repeatedly asked for context, clarification and more details - all things needed to provide a useful answer. You were reluctant to provide any. That often leads some to downvote the question.

Comment: *"That said, you were repeatedly asked for context, clarification and more details - all things needed to provide a useful answer. You were reluctant to provide any. That often leads some to downvote the question"* - without taking a look at your two questions, what Joe says is very important. People on this stack are very active and engaged to posts, so providing timely feedback and clarification is important to obtain good answers and avoid Downvotes and closure (posting a Q and just leaving it unattended here is a no-go, contrast to other sites like perhaps SO where answers take more time).

Comment: If you posed questions on Stack Overflow that were vaguely worded and then didn't clarify them, they would be closed. No difference. Many of my excellent questions on SO attracted downvotes almost immediately.

Comment: @Kilisi: I disagree that my question was vaguely worded. What **I** wanted to know was pretty clear I think. Some people however demanded more context and background information, that I don't think helped to answer the question. I provided it anyway hoping that would calm them. I was wrong.

Comment: You got an answer to the first question although the question was vague. But the main issue with it is (reading between the lines of comments) you're conflating the day with the overtime. When it's actually unimportant and confusing to do so. I didn't downvote or even read the second question.

Comment: @DarkCygnus: "posting a Q and just leaving it unattended here is a no-go". I find this to be a very strange sentiment. After all, this is Q&A site, not a forum. The goal is not primarily help the OP, but to create a collection of great questions and answers. It should be obvious, that that takes time. Who cares in a year from now (if my questions is then still around), that it took me an hour to respond to a comment?

Comment: So you may have worked nightshift Friday for 8 hours ending Saturday 6AM, but in terms of rates that may be shown as 2 hours worked on Friday, 6 on Saturday. The fact that it was nightshift only affects the hourly rate change if any. And while you may think the question was clear, many people obviously did not.

Comment: @Kilisi: Thank you for your answer on my first question. I actually accepted a similar one on my second question. I still disagree though that the question was vague. How could I've anticipated that people would equate overtime with overtime pay? That still seems strange to me.

Comment: There is no telling why people think what they think. I'm sorry you feel you had a bad experience. We have a well intentioned community here for the most part.

Comment: @user1785730 I'm just pointing out what I've observed is the dynamics of this site. I'm sorry there are folks that are quick to DV or vote to close. Fortunately, there are ways to navigate that, like posting here on Meta as you did, or posting here on meta a [meta-tag:reopen-request] where you expose your post and ask the community to vote to reopen... that being said, I'm sorry you had this perception of hostility; I wish you nothing but the best and welcome you to The Workplace, and hope your future experiences are better :)

Comment: SE site had rather strict, sometimes not so obvious rules, and Workplace tends to be somewhat annoying, since the rules are even less clear then elsewhere. (Since the whole topic is very soft and fuzzy area - compared to "My code does not work, why?" questions.) Your first question was too vague, though, and was closed rightfully. That said, some folks commenting on it were definitely kinda mean. (Me included, frankly.)

Comment: Yes, Workspace is as toxic as the real workspaces where the people are working. But it was asked so many times, it's definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Wow - it is well known fact that SO is *the most toxic site* on the internet and in the universe (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=toxic). :) (Side note: you may want to edit out part of re-asking the same question as that is definitely not something you'd even try to do on SO - very unclear why you expect re-asking to be ok on other SE sites).

Answer (score 7):

I think the issue is you think that people closing your questions was an attack on you. It is not, it is just people treating the question on its merits.

You could have, at any stage, modified your questions, adding the context people were asking for, and the question would have become answerable. You should note that your second question had more context

People even tried to help you by guessing what the context is.

You decided you would rather keep people confused, and not reveal any meaningful information that could help people understand what you were looking for.

10s of different people added comments asking for clarification, or tried to explain to you that there is not one global standard, but instead of helping these people you tried your hardest to withhold context.

Eventually, we managed to get it out of you that it's for calculating overtime hours worked, to determine how much time in lieu you have, with a focus on Germany? Where overtime is simply the number of hours you worked in excess of a contracted amount.

The answer is then it doesn't matter what day you associate the hours to. Addition is commutative. German law recognises that working on Sunday has a special status, and work on Sunday is generally prohibited between midnight and midnight. So to be consistent with that, you could associate hours according to the day.

But ultimately it doesn't matter. You don't need to associate hours to days. You need to associate hours to periods specified in your contract. If you want to break it down further, that's a stylistic decision for you to make.

Comment: The problem is that you (and others) interpreted way too much into my question. My question at its core was very simple. You don't need to know *why* I was asking this question. If you think it doesn't matter to which day to associate the hours, you could've just written an answer stating that.

Comment: And that it might be problematic to lump together overtime with different payout value would've been much appreciated feedback. I have to admit, that I wasn't thinking much on that, but I don't think that it completely invalidates my question.

Comment: But the behaviour from you I perceived as outright hostile. I know that it wasn't personal, you probably just took it upon yourself to defend some standards of this community that you felt I were violating. Nevertheless it has been very frustrating.

Comment: @user1785730 The issue is that without some additional context, your question is meaningless. Which is why people voted to close it. If you had come out from the start and explained that you were trying to build a tool that allowed people to track hours worked for the purposes of ensuring their holidays were correctly calculated, people would have responded differently and answered accordingly.

Comment: @user1785730 "You don't need to know why I was asking this question." The community, whose opinion that you asked, disagrees with you on that point.

Comment: "that's a stylistic decision for you to make." No, it's not. There is laws about that. And the OP specifically asked if there is laws about that. It's fine to tell them "The laws don't cover that, it's your decision" if that is indeed the case, but I get the impression that you don't actually know that.

Comment: @nvoigt Feel free to quote the law. My understanding is, that overtime worked in excess during the duration of the contracted period.

Comment: So what does the law say about overtime in excess of a shift from 8 PM to 6 AM? does it belong to the day before or the day after? Because there are laws saying you may not do more than 2 hours of overtime per day. So if your shift ended at 10PM, would you be allowed to do 4 hours overtime, 2 on that day until midnight and then another two "the next day"? Those are interesting questions and I don't know the answer, but I know there will be an answer because laws don't tend to go the "don't care, do as you like" way.

Comment: The OP explicitely asked in the body of their first question "Is this codified by law? Are there regulations?" What more context do you need?

Comment: @nvoigt Filling out a spreadsheet? No, probably not. Maybe if the spreadsheet will be submitted somewhere?

Comment: Well, if you *want* to misunderstand their question, sure, you can think that way.

Comment: "I want to attribute a nightshift to a day and am not sure wether to choose the starting or the ending day... I want to attribute the hole shift as it is to a day" My impression they just want to fill out a spreadsheet. Maybe they want to validate overtime calculations too.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was closed because it was, indeed vague.

overtime policies differ from company to company, contract to contract, state to state, country to country.

The fact that you did not include a country tag, or if in the USA, asked about a state, made it so vague as to be unanswerable.

Just in the USA, it differs wildly from state to state.  Nevada requiring all work in the same day to be paid as OT, other states such as NJ only require OT to be paid after 40 hours.  Some companies have a contracts where they pay OT over 35 hours.

So, how is there any possible general answer to this question.

You could have done any of the following.

- responded to any of the numerous queries and requests for clarification.
- edited your original post after it was closed
- added a country tag
- included the industry
- included whether it was a union job.

Because context matters in the workplace, you failing to provide resulted in it's closure.

Because **YOU FAILED** to provide detail does not make this place "toxic".  In fact, I find some irony that you made the accusation with a venomous post.

Comment: **YOU FAILED** to actually read my question. Otherwise you would know that I wasn't interested in in any of these policies. I even defined precisely, what I mean by overtime. And I admitted that what many of you supposed I was doing wouldn't work. Your insinuation that I did not respond to requests for clarification is just absurd.

Comment: The original question said they are interested in "Germany". And Germany has indeed nation wide labor laws governing overtime. I don't know the answer on top of my head because I don't work nightshifts, but everything needed to answer is right there in the question. I think with a *minimum* of good will (making the country explicitely mentioned in the body a tag for people that don't read properly) this could have been a good question instead of being nuked from orbit.

Answer (score -1):

Quite frankly, I read your questions and you are right. At least the first one was a clear question that should **not** have been closed. Or downvoted for that matter.

I have tagged it with the country given in the body text (which everybody should have been able to do) and voted to reopen it. To be honest I don't know the answer, but the question is perfectly clear and does not need any further clarification.

Anybody who voted to close this as unclear can ask themselves the following question: do I know *two or more conflicting answers* so I cannot give one of them in good faith until the question is clarified?

If the answer is "no" then why did you vote to close it?

If it is unclear *to you*, then don't answer. Only if you know for a fact that it is unclear to *everybody*, because multiple conflicting answers exist, should you vote to close, to keep others, who might not know about the conflict from answering.

---

That said, what could you, the OP do better? Well, you triggered a few responses because you did not focus on the core of your question.

You wrote:

> Which option would you choose?

This is a clear red flag. You are asking for opinions. I bet half the voters did not even read past this line and just voted to close. Only later did you specify you did not really look for opinions, but for laws. And looking for relevant labor laws in context of a specific country is a great question. But you buried it. Under a survey for opinions, that is a reason to close, here *and* at Stack Overflow.

I have edited your question into a shape where it will hopefully be reopened.

Comment: When asked what the data is used for: "There is no further context." Unless German law mandates you fill out spreadsheets a certain way (for maybe personal use), I fail to see how you can say this is answerable. There may be contexts where filling out worked hours may need to be done a certain way. Maybe if the spreadsheet is going to be sent to some authority. But OP won't tell us the purpose of the spreadsheet.

Comment: The OP clearly asked "Is this codified by law? Are there regulations?" Isn't that all context you need to answer with a section of the regulations or law, or alternatively, if you know that law really well, tell them that there are none? That is factual information that is good to have, no matter what context.

Comment: The original question " I'm particularly interested in the situation in Germany, but hints from anywhere are fine. Please mention in your answer to which country your rules apply."  makes it unanswerable.  The help even spells it out: To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Comment: In principle, if a question is unclear to you (not to everybody, just to you as an individual) you can vote to close. You can also ask for clarity, which many people did. Voting is a personal thing and should be treated as such.

Comment: @RoryAlsop So based on this I should vote every question about labor law that is not Germany or the US as unclear, because I personally know nothing about it?

Comment: reductio ad absurdum is exactly what it says. Absurd.

Comment: Well, to each their own, I find it profoundly absurd that we closed a perfectly answerable question, because 5 people *who had no clue what an answer would look like* voted to close it.